# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function idbancoExiste() in

Tags: sql-insert

Estou fazendo o cadastro de dados bancarios para usuarios de uma pagina. Ao realizar o teste do codigo no localhost esta tudo funcionando bem, mas quando faço upload para o servidor que tenho ele apresenta o erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function idbancoExiste() in /home/u619105775/domains/airrocket.com.br/public_html/afiliados/minhaconta.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u619105775/domains/airrocket.com.br/public_html/afiliados/minhaconta.php on line 23

Segue o código:

```
<?php

session_start();
require 'funcs/conexion.php';
require 'funcs/funcs.php';

$errors = array();

if(!empty($_POST)){

$cpf =$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cpf']);
$numero =$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['numero']);
$nomebanco = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nomebanco']);
$agencia =$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['agencia']);
$conta=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['conta']);

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

if(cpfExiste($cpf))
    {
        $errors[] = "CPF ja existe";
    }
if(idbancoExiste($idUsuario))     <== LINHA DO ERROR
    {   
    $errors[] = "OOps, já existe um registro para este usuario."; 
    }

    $registro =registraCpf($cpf, $numero, $nomebanco, $agencia, $conta, $idUsuario);
        if ($registro) {
  header("location:minhaconta.php");
} 
}
```

---

archivo funcs.php

```
function idbancoExiste($idUsuario)
{
    global $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbbancarios WHERE idusuario= ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$idUsuario);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if ($num > 0){
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Everson, como o erro informa, ele não está conseguindo encontrar a função  `idbancoExiste`, verifique o caminho que o código `require 'funcs/funcs.php';` está fazendo.

Comment: @Gerep Bom dia, já verifiquei todo o codigo. No localhost esta tudo certo, mas quando publico a pagina, aparece esse erro, já olhei o versão do php e fiz outros testes e até agora nada. Teria alguma outra dica? vou verificar essa função novamente.

Comment: Acredito que o problema não esteja no seu código da função mas sim na importação feita pelo `require`. Tente trabalhar com o caminho absoluto e não relativo, talvez dê certo.

Comment: @Gerep, continuo com o mesmo error, tentei o caminho absoluto desta forma:  $pathFile = realpath('funcs'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'funcs.php') ;
if ($pathFile) {
 
 include($pathFile);
} else {
 echo 'Error: File not found! <br>';
 echo 'Path: ' . $pathFile . '<br>';
}